# How to catch ECONNRESET error from 'net' module in node js? And prevent whole program from getting terminated?

Tags: node.js, networking, error-handling, tcp

If I try very basic code from NodeJS docs

```js
//CLIENT.js
    const net = require('net');
    const client = net.createConnection({ port: 8124 }, () => {
      // 'connect' listener.
      console.log('connected to server!');
      client.write('I am client');
    });
    client.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(data)
      client.write('I am client');
      //client.end(); I don't want to close the connection
    });
    client.on('end', () => {
      console.log('disconnected from server');
    });

//SERVER.js
    const net = require('net');
    const server = net.createServer((c) => {
      // 'connection' listener.
      console.log('client connected');
      c.on('end', () => {
        console.log('client disconnected');
      });
      c.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        c.write("I am server");
      })
      c.pipe(c);
    });
    server.on('error', (err) => {
      console.log("Something went worng"); //I hope this will be triggered in cases of error
    });
    server.listen(8124, () => {
      console.log('server bound');
    });
```

Now the Problem:-

- I start the SERVER.js `node SERVER.js`
- Then I start CLIENT.js `node CLIENT.js` on a different CMD tab.
- So far all well... 'I am server I am client............'

**Note** I am using Windows 10

- NOW, I close the client side program by simply pressing `ctrl + C`, then server side program gets terminated and it throws 'read ECONNRESET'

Full error log

```
events.js:292
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Error: read ECONNRESET
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

I understand why this error is caused theoretically, So I tried resolving it in a different manner, as the program was not triggering `server.on('error')` event, it simply terminated the whole server program.

So what I tried was

```js
//SERVER.js

    const net = require('net');
    const server = net.createServer((c) => {
      // 'connection' listener.
      console.log('client connected');
try {
      c.on('end', () => {
        console.log('client disconnected');
      });
      c.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        c.write("I am server");
      })
      c.pipe(c);
} catch(e){
//hoping of catching the error
console.log("Here is your error", e)
// !!! But no error is caught here and the program still gets completely terminated
}
    });
    server.on('error', (err) => {
      console.log("Something went worng"); //I hope this will be triggered in cases of error
    });
    server.listen(8124, () => {
      console.log('server bound');
    });
```

So How should I deal with " read ECONNRESET " error ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap around try-catch entire code and in catch invoke the main/starting function again it will spin up again, But it will go in an endless loop of try-catch till your service for which you are getting ECONNRESET is not up again,

Make sure the service your application relies on is 99.99999% time up and let your application fail and restart. (for example, using PM2 type utility)

Comment: I tried whole code inside the try block(NO LOOPING), but nothing showed up inside the catch, and program got terminated with exactly the same error :-(

Comment: But to note I only got this error when I execute client & server on same computer, if I run server on ngrok's tunned port, then I am Not getting this error. But 'disconnect' event is not triggered either.

Comment: May be you are using same port for server and client, also in node we have process.uncaughtexception which catches any error